# Prove that for all $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $, $i_{\mathbb R}Rf$ iff $f$ is one-to-one.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathcal F = \{f \mid f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$ and
>    define relationship $R$ on $\mathcal F$ as follows:
>
> $$R = \{(f,g) \in \mathcal F \times \mathcal F \mid \exists h \in  \mathcal F (f = h \circ g)\}$$
>
> Prove that for all $f \in \mathcal F$, $i_{\mathbb R}Rf$ iff $f$ is
>   one-to-one.

$$i_{\mathbb R} = \{(x,x) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$$

My attempt:

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose $i_{\mathbb R}Rf$. Exists function $h \in F$, such that

$$i_{\mathbb R} = h \circ f $$

Suppose $(x,a_1) \in f$ and $(x,a_2) \in f$

Since $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, there exist $b_1,b_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $(a_1,b_1) \in h$ and $(a_2,b_2) \in h$

Then we have $(x,b_1) \in i_{\mathbb R}$ and  $(x,b_2) \in i_{\mathbb R}$, which means that $b_1 = b_2$

Since $h$ is a function, $a_1 = a_2$

$(\leftarrow)$

Suppose $f$ is one-to-one. Define $f^{-1}$ as

$$f^{-1} = \{(y,x) \mid (x,y) \in f\} $$

Then $f^{-1} \circ f = i_{\mathbb R}$, and thus $i_{\mathbb R}Rf$

$\Box$

---

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that I see is that you have assumed that $f^{-1}$ has a domain of $\mathbb R$ in the last part.  That is only true if $f$ is also surjective.  It is true that every injective function has a left-inverse, but you have to define such a function for the entire domain with a little more care.  Not that it's a difficult task, but it's part of the proof.

Comment: My reasoning was that, since $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $f$ is one-to-one, then it will also be surjective, hence the domain of the inverse will be $\mathbb R$. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @Nelver That is only true with finite sets.  For instance, $x\mapsto e^x$ is injective but not surjective as a function from $\mathbb R$ to itself.

Comment: Could you tell me how I should reword the $\leftarrow$ part of the proof, please?

Comment: @Nelver A simple piecewise function, like $g(x)=y$ if $(y,x)\in f$ and $0$ otherwise is a sufficient definition.

Comment: Nice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[ EDITED ] I'm not competent enough to assess the proof you have proposed ( though it seems right to me). . Let me try an indirect proof of (-->) using contraposition.

[image]